# Take an array with just one object and transform to a single array of values

Tags: javascript

Given the following:

```
let arr = [
    { name: 'AAA' },
    { name: 'BBB' },
    { name: 'CCC' },
    { name: 'DDD' },
    { name: 'EEE' },
    { name: 'FFF' }
 ];
```

I'm trying to covert the above to a new array with just the values. I tried:

```
console.log(Object.values(arr));
```

but this didn't work.

The end result that I am after is just the values within the one new array, that is:

```
new_arr = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF'];
```

Comment: `const new_arr = arr.map(o => o.name);`

Comment: try this `arr.map(({name}) => name)`

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.map(value =>  value.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array map or each or any other loop iteration. The simple one is given below.

```js
let arr = [
    { name: 'AAA' },
    { name: 'BBB' },
    { name: 'CCC' },
    { name: 'DDD' },
    { name: 'EEE' },
    { name: 'FFF' }
 ];

console.log(arr);

const newarr = arr.map(function(e, i) {
  return e.name
});

console.log(newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try this syntax

```
let arr = [
{ name: 'AAA' },
{ name: 'BBB' },
{ name: 'CCC' },
{ name: 'DDD' },
{ name: 'EEE' },
{ name: 'FFF' }
];

let array = arr.map((e)=>Object.values(e)[0])

console.log(array);
```

Comment: that's quite a nifty way of doing it.